# Unable to access resx file in .net Core 3

Tags: .net-core, resx, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

Have added new .Resx file into Resources folder under .Net Core Web 3 project.

When try to access resx file its not available on controller or validation attribute.

What is the right way to work with Resx files in .Net Core.

Comment: Please, share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Configuring Localization in Controller, you could refer to the following steps

1.Configure Localization in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method and set cultures in  the `Startup.Configure` method. The localization middleware must be configured before any middleware which might check the request culture :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       //Adds the localization services to the services container. The code above also sets the resources path to "Resources"
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

2.The `ConfigureServices` method sets the `ResourcesPath` to "Resources", so the project relative path for the home controller's French resource file is `Resources/Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx`. Alternatively, you can use folders to organize resource files. For the home controller, the path would be `Resources/Controllers/HomeController.fr.resx`.

[image]

Then use `IStringLocalizer` which uses the ResourceManager and ResourceReader to provide culture-specific resources at run time to access Resx files in Controller .

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = _localizer["Your application description page."];

        return View();
    }
}
```

For more details , you could refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which contains the sample code and DataAnnotations localization.

Comment: do we need separate view as well like, `About.fr.cshtml` and `about.en.cshtml` and validation will work like, attribute based validation.

Comment: No . Regarding the naming and use of resource files for both view localization and data annotation localization, you can refer to the official document link in the last line of my response above.